# How to make poisson noise from uniform random numbers using central limit theorem?

Tags: math, poisson, approximation

Using the fact that Gaussian(λ=σ) is an approximation of Poisson(λ), I want to compute an approximation of Poisson noise using only uniform random numbers without using factorials.

There are two things I have no clue.

1. How to approximate gaussian noise from uniform noise.
2. How to approximate Poisson noise with Gaussian noise when λ is small.

Comment: 1. If you don't care about execution time, take the sum of N uniform drawings.

Comment: 2. Poisson with small λ is not well approximated by a Guassian.

Comment: The "without using factorials" condition is peculiarly specific. Can you explain where that's coming from?

Comment: I want to implement a realistic film grain effect in GLSL.
Due to the structure of the shader, it is not possible to perform recursive calculations or calculations that require different amounts of calculation for each pixel. I mean entertainment purpose, so using LUT are allowed. any approximation is acceptable.

Comment: I tried the Box-Muller method, but it didn't work. X = mu + sigma * sqrt( -2.0 * log(rand())) * sin( 2.0 * PI * rand() )